# Surrounding an L-shaped tromino

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, tiling

You are given an L-shaped tromino, shown below. Can you surround it by 10 more L-shaped trominoes? The new trominoes can be rotated and must touch the original tromino at an edge or a corner.

[image]

This puzzle comes from the great game [Good Fences](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.isohedral.goodfences&hl=en&gl=US).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.  Didn’t really have a strategy, just played around a bit and came to it after a couple tries.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Οn a 6x6 square we choose the sides with the 3 empty squares.  Then we put the given tromino equidistantly from the 4 sides and we fill the empty squares with trominoes. 6x6=36-(11x3)=3

[image: 26]

Here is another arrangement where 4 trominoes touch, corner to corner, the given tromino.

[image: 27]

Comment: This isn't different from the other answer, as far as I can see.